# Windows 10: setup SLIP over an USB serial line

Tags: windows

I'm trying to connect to an embedded device using SLIP in Windows 10. I can easily connect to it in Ubuntu by using `slattach` and creating a new network interface. Is there a way to do something similar in Windows? I tried searching in "Set up a new connection" in the control panel but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue also. I haven't got it all working yet, but the following steps are what I have so far on how to set up a SLIP connection to an embedded device on Windows 10.

First you have to install a modem which isn't really a modem.

1. Device manager->Action->Add Legacy Hardware
2. Next->Install the hardware that I manually select from a list->Next
3. Modems->Next
4. Don't detect my modem, I will select it from a list->Next
5. Communications cable between two computers->Next
6. Select the COM port that you will connect to the embedded device with->Next->Finish

Now you have a "Modem" which is actually a cable linked to the COM port to your device.

Next, set up a connection using this modem.

1. Settings->Network & Internet->Dial Up->Setup a new connection
2. Connection to the Internet->Next
3. Set up a new connection anyway
4. No, create a new connection (you only see this if you have an existing connection)
5. Dial Up
6. If you have more than one modem, select the communications cable between two computers one. If you only have one, you won't see this option
7. Enter a made up phone number, say '0'->Connect
8. When it tries to connect to the modem, click Skip.
9. Close

You can further change the adaptor settings to remove the phone number, and the prompt for a username and password.

Very interested to know if anyone else has this fully working, or is working on this. I still have lots of questions about how a connection is established, IP addresses & other things.